# Entity containing another class persist into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, jpa, entity

I have a requirement where i need to persist an entity to DB.
This entity consist of another class. I want the classes toString data to be persisted.

Below is the example:

```
class A {
 String x;
 B b;
}

Class B {
 String y;
 public String toString() {
   return y;
 }
```

MySql Table DataTable(column1 varchar, column2 varchar)

When i em.persist(A), column1 should store value of x from class A,
and column2 should store value of y from class B

How to do it ?

Comment: You should avoid using `toString()` as a form of serialization.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i dont want serialize it, just want to save it as a string to table.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just do this:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Column(name="column1", length=100)
    String x;

    @Column(name="column2", length=100)
    String bValue;

    B b;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void getBValue() {
        bValue = b.toString();
    }

    /* getters, setters, blah here */
}
```